# JSP - not sure how to check user login detail from database

Tags: jsp

Should I have:
1) A login bean that stores the username and password inputted from the login form, and
2) A servelet that retrieves details from the bean and the database to validate user details

Flow of events could be something like this:
login.jsp (View) -> loginbean (model) -> mySQLservelet

Am I thinking right? :P

Answer (score 0):

Typically a Java EE Web application delegates the security to the containers. So you declare that your application's resources (URLs) require authorrisation (**this** URL can be accessed by **these** roles) then when you deply the app you associate users and groups with those roles.

The application server will then be associated with some user registry (LDAP, Operating System, simple text file or whatever) and when the user attempts to access the URL they get challenged and their authorisation then checked. You don't need to write any code.

This established a security context which can be flowed elsewhere (for example into an EJB), and if you do need to do finer grained authorisation checks you can access the user's principal information in your code.